# How do I override the bash "noclobber" option?

Tags: bash

The `bash` `noclobber` option prevents one from overwriting files with redirection. But sometimes I really want to. `csh` has a similar option and it can be over-ridden by putting a `!` before the filenames. Is there any way to do this with `bash`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes.  Append `|` to the redirection operator to form `>|`.  This is in [§ 3.6.2 of the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), q.v.

> If the redirection operator is ‘>’, and the noclobber option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file. If the redirection operator is ‘>|’, or the redirection operator is ‘>’ and the noclobber option is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file named by word exists.

Visit [this tutorial about the noclobber option](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-keep-file-safe-from-overwriting.html). It might be of help.

Answer (score 6):

Use `|` ("pipe") in `bash`, instead of `!` ("bang") as you would in `csh`.  For example:

```
echo done >| out
```

Note that if you want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` *and* override `noclobber`, neither `>|&` nor `&>|` will work; use the long form instead:

```
cmd-with-errors done >| out 2>&1
```

Comment: Do you know why `err &>| out` doesn't work?